# Trigger file download to EC2 Windows instance after edit in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, automation, amazon-sns

Attempting to architect a solution that's as automated as possible for downloading a script from S3 after it's edited to a specific drive & directory in a windows EC2 instance.

As I see it at the moment, I believe I can use the S3 Event Notifications to trigger whenever a file has been edited in the bucket itself.  What I'm struggling with is how I can utilize a script to download it automatically from there.  I know SNS would be an option to subscribe to the S3 Notifications and this instance would have a public IP address.

I've automated tasks exporting TO S3 using Batch files in the Windows Task Scheduler with:

```
AWS CP or AWS SYNC
```

But I want to do it the other way around and don't quite see another question with a similar ask. 
 What's the missing cog in the machine here?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The best model is to have the instance **pull** the file from Amazon S3. Can you tell us more about how the file will be used? For example, could you add a _pull_ (`aws s3 cp`) step immediately before it is used, so that it always grabs the most recent version? How often is it used?

Comment: You could trigger a Lambda function on the S3 object being uploaded, and have the Lambda function use SSM Run Command to run a script on all EC2 instances that have specific matching tags. That script pulls the latest file from S3. That said, I like @JohnRotenstein suggestion of pulling the script on demand, each time it's run.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the goal is to essentially have it pulled down to a directory on the server from a bucket whenever it is edited.  I agree that I'd prefer to have it automatically pulled down on a interval basis, but the requirement is for any time there's a change to the file.

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as "put it on the instance whenever there is a change", my suggestion is "get the latest copy whenever it is being used". I was not suggesting to pull it down on an _interval_ basis, I was suggesting pulling it down whenever it is about to be used. This is slightly wasteful if the file rarely changes, but it would be more efficient if the file changes a lot but is rarely used. The end result is that the program using the file always has the latest version (which should meet the business requirements) and it is simpler/more reliable to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

1. Use the S3 Event Notification with SNS as you mentioned.
2. Create a web service running on the Windows EC2 instance that you can register to receive the S3 notifications (e.g. using python on whatever you are comfortable with).
3. On receipt of the notification have the web service use the AWS SDK that you should also co-install on the Windows EC2 instance to GET the S3 object and store it in the directory of your choice.

Look at this [AWS documentation article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html) for how to register the web service for SNS notifications.